# Altium: All connection lines going to absolute origin

Tags: pcb, altium

Problem
Sometimes all the connection lines go to the "absolute origin" in the PCB layout.  It is rare enough that I never remember what sequence I took to get this to happen.  In the attached image, I did route->auto route->component and then all the connection lines went to the absolute origin.  It's possible to work with the lines but they're obviously annoying and "wrong".  I can view->hide connections but they will come back eventually.

Work around
The only way I've been able to work around this is to copy the PCB, create a new one and paste the components, etc., into the new PCB.  That usually works.  I would prefer to not have to do that.

I've had this problem with many versions of Altium.  It doesn't come up often but it does come up.  Any ideas would be welcome.
[image: connection line problem]

[image: selected outside]

Comment: What happens if you "Select-->Outside" rectangle, drag an area just around the physical PCB, and then look at the "PCB List" panel?  What's listed?

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen When I select all outside the PCB, the PCB List becomes empty.  The connection lines do get highlighted but there is nothing there.  There aren't even nets listed in the PCB List when the outside-only is selected so the connection lines shouldn't be there.